# Joining two arrays by key name for Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm pretty new to angular and typescript and I've run into an issue. I have two arrays that I need merged into one based on their category-id. Both arrays include some values that the other does not have. These arrays will change based on user inputs so I have no way of knowing ahead of time what the length of each array will be. I do know that "category-id" will always be included in each array, however, which is why I would like to merge the 2 arrays based on that. Thanks for any help.

Example:

```
arr1 = [
{category-id: car, category-value: mustang},    
{category-id: convertible, category-value: softTop}
]
arr2 = [
{category-id: car, category-feature: convertible},
{category-id: truck, category-value: ranger},
{category-id: convertible, category-feature: blue}
]
```

Desired Result:

```
arr3 = [
{category-id: car, category-value:mustang, category-feature: convertible},
{category-id: truck, category-value: ranger},
{category-id: convertible, category-value: softTop, category-feature: blue}
]
```

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. It's not the most elegant solution, you could do it in 2 lines using lodash or Typescript LINQ or Immutable.js but it's pure.

```
const arr1 = [
    { categoryid: 'car', categoryvalue: 'mustang'},    
    { categoryid: 'convertible', categoryvalue: 'softTop'}
]
const arr2 = [
    { categoryid: 'car', categoryfeature: 'convertible'},
    { categoryid: 'truck', categoryvalue: 'ranger'},
    { categoryid: 'convertible', categoryfeature: 'blue'}
]

const arr3 = []
for (let x of arr1)
{
    const found = arr2.filter(y => y.categoryid === x.categoryid).shift();
    if (found)
       arr3.push({ ...x, ...found });
}
arr3.push(... arr2.filter(z=> arr1.map(x=>x.categoryid).indexOf(z.categoryid) === -1 ))
```

So the trick here is to use the [spread](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html) operator. It will automatically merge two object by their field names.

Comment: Did exactly what I needed. The spread operator was new to me. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding. Don't forget to upvote the answer.